# How do I add a unique user to form from Model that shares Foreign Key?

Tags: python, django

I'm getting the following error:

> author = ForeignKey(User, db_column="user") TypeError: **init**()
> missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'

I've tried adding the positional argument to the form but that didn't fix it. I know that with the on_delete=CASCADING attribute it will delete all objects that have references to it. I know it's a form issue but I can't seem to find any answer which is why I'm posting this. Any help/guidance would be much appreciated!

models.py

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Review(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Movie Title', max_length=100)
    rating = models.IntegerField('Personal Rating', validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(10)])
    comment = models.TextField('Comment', blank=True)
    datetime_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Show table in /admin page
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
from datetime import datetime

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import ForeignKey
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms

from . import models
from .models import Review


class UploadReview(ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField()
    rating = forms.IntegerField()
    comment = forms.Textarea()
    datetime_posted = datetime.now()
    author = ForeignKey(User, db_column="user")

    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ['title', 'rating', 'comment']
        exclude = ['datetime_posted', 'author']
```

Comment: Please refer this document https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a ForeginKey in the ModelForm.

```
from django.db.models import ForeignKey
class UploadReview(ModelForm):
     .....
     author = ForeignKey(User, db_column="user")
```

This is for DB models. For ModelForms you should use [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField)

```
     author = forms.ModelChoiceField(
          queryset=User.objects.all(),
          empty_label="(Nothing)"
     )
```